# multiple scrollable views in a single screen android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, scrollview

I have to Design Screen with multiple view inside single screen ie., More than one scrollable (Listview,gridview,Horizontal scrollview) Layouts in a single screen.   like [How to Design xml layout like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3nHH.png)

Comment: Everything you need to create that layout is listed in the screenshot you linked to. So what is your actual question?

Comment: I have created all layout what i have mentioned in screenshot. But problem is screen entirely not scrolling. Listview scrolling with in 200dp. layouts should scroll ie., entire screen has to scroll.

Comment: can you tell me the layout design and its scrolling behaviors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Coordinatorlayout
   - Toolbar
   - NestedScrollView
      - LinearLayout (Vertical)
         - Linearlayout(Horizontal)
              - EditText (for Search)
              - Spinner or Button (for Filters)
         - RecyclerView (with LinearLayoutManager Horizontal with only 1 column)
         - Textview for (DELIVERY OPTIONS BY CUISINE)
         - RecyclerView (with LinearLayoutManager Horizontal with 4 columns)
         - Textview for (ALL DELIVERY OPTIONS)
         - RecyclerView (with LinearLayoutManager Vertical)
```

P.s Cards with ImageView and TextView as Layouts inside RecyclerView

This should do the trick.